# How to use jquery to swap the position of multiple images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm a novice at jquery/javascript, so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.

I have 3 images and I want to be able to change their position when a user clicks either the second or the third one.  For example, if the user clicks image #2, I want image #2 to become image #1 (left-most), then image #3 becomes image #2 (middle) and finally image #1 becomes image #3 (right-most).  If the user clicks image #3, I want image #3 to become image #1 (left-most), then image #1 becomes image #2 (middle) and finally image #2 becomes image #3 (right-most).

If the user clicks the first image, I don't want anything to happen.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ImageSwap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = new Array("http://i.imgur.com/QWso5yB.png", "http://i.imgur.com/O4X3egC.png", "http://i.imgur.com/w3p2qLp.png");
    $('#first').bind('click', firstChannel);
    $('#second').bind('click', secondChannel);
});
function firstChannel() {
    var tempImg = img[0];
    img[1] = img[2];
    img[2] = tempImg;
    $('#home').attr('src',img[0]);
    $('#first').attr('src',img[1]);
    $('#second').attr('src',img[2]);
};
function secondChannel() {
    var tempImg = img[0];
    img[0] = img[2];
    img[2] = img[1];
    img[1] = tempImg;
    $('#home').attr('src',img[0]);
    $('#first').attr('src',img[1]);
    $('#second').attr('src',img[2]);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="home" src="http://i.imgur.com/QWso5yB.png">
    <img id="first" src="http://i.imgur.com/O4X3egC.png">
    <img id="second" src="http://i.imgur.com/w3p2qLp.png">
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking the 2nd and 3rd images, nothing happens.  What the heck am I doing wrong here?  Is there an easier way to do this?  I've been pulling my hair out searching everywhere but can't seem to find an answer.  Many thanks in advance for any feedback you can give me...

Comment: So you basically want to build a slideshow?

Comment: I guess...I'm using this like a TV channel selector, so the left-most channel will be the active one.  The user has to click to make anything happen (ie, like changing the channel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it simple? ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zekadahihi/1/edit?html,css,console,output)***

A parent element:

```
    <div id="channels">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QWso5yB.png">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O4X3egC.png">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w3p2qLp.png">
    </div>
```

and some `prepend()`:

```
    $(function () {
        var $chn = $("#channels");
        $chn.on("click","img", function(){
           $chn.prepend( this );
        });
    });
```

I mean, if the **first image represents the *current channel***, than all you need to do (as above) is to **prepend the clicked element**. To style the first element simply use CSS `img:first-child`

---

**EDIT: KEEP ORDER**

***[jsBin demo with Order](http://jsbin.com/bujeyahegi/1/edit)***

If *appending* creates at some point a mess of channels order,
I'd suggest you to:

Create a MAIN or *currently watching* big image and place all channels inside a parent:

```
    <img id="current">


    <div id="channels">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/a7b&text=1">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/ba7&text=2">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/7ba&text=3">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/bb7&text=4">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/77a&text=5">
       <img src="//placehold.it/90x40/ab7&text=6">
    </div>
```

Than on a channel-click, set the clicked image src to the BIG image, and hide the clicked one:

```
$(function () {

    var $img = $("#channels").find("img");
    var $current = $("#current"); // The big image

    $img.on("click", function(){
        $current[0].src = this.src;
        $img.show();
        $(this).hide();
    }).eq(0).click();

});
```

***[Example with a better UI](http://jsbin.com/bujeyahegi/2/edit)***

Comment: Wrong answer. He wants to perform circular left shift, your method just inserts  the clicked image at the beginning. `prepend` does not perform circular left shift. [For detail...](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp)

Comment: @KhalidHussain that's not true. He wants the clicked image to become the *image that was current*. Now if you think again that it's about a circular-shift you'll see that your comment fails. So *defacto* that the shift is unusual I just simplified the task of... well... really shifting all the other images by one place.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Also avoid posting links to `w3schools`. They are not related in any case to W3C, the site is not maintained by a programming community and they sell fake diplomas. (Not to talk about the vaste inaccuracy of technical details that make w3schools actually a bad place to stat learning.)

Comment: Good idea and much simpler, but yes I am trying to slide the channels like turning a dial. I think this would be much easier for users to understand in this context because the channels always stay in the same order.  Thank you though, I will keep this code in mind for future applications!

Comment: @Byron if you want to keep always the order see this nice example: http://jsbin.com/bujeyahegi/1/edit >> even with unlimited number of channels you'e done in a couple of lines of jQuery.

Comment: @Byron or, for a more professional User Interface (without jumpy stuff) I'd go for: http://jsbin.com/bujeyahegi/2/edit